# I have two array object, array A have store groups object and array B have stores object

Tags: javascript, arraylist, arrayobject

the first array contains objects having unique **store_group_id**.

```
let arrayA = [
  {
    store_group_id: 'ID0-y6z-85',
    store_group_name: 'Store Group A',
    store_group_desc: 'This is the desc of store group A'
  },
  {
    store_group_id: 'ID4-y7z-27',
    store_group_name: 'Store Group B',
    store_group_desc: 'This is the desc of store group B'
  }
]
```

the second array contains objects of stores with *store_group_ids* inside **storeGroups**.

```
let arrayB = [
  {
    store_id: 'store 1',
    store_name: 'store A',
    description: 'This is the description of store 1',
    org_id: 'org id 1',
    storeGroups: [ 'ID0-y6z-85', 'ID4-y7z-27' ]
  },
  {
    store_id: 'store 2',
    store_name: 'store B',
    description: 'This is the description of store 2',
    org_id: 'org id 1',
    storeGroups: [ 'ID0-y6z-85', 'ID4-y7z-27' ]
  },
  {
    store_id: 'store 5',
    store_name: 'store E',
    description: 'This is the description of store 5',
    org_id: 'org id 1',
    storeGroups: [ 'ID0-y6z-85' ]
  }
]
```

I want to have a single array object mapping with the store _group_id of both the arrays.
I want the resultant array something like the given below.

```
arrayResult = [
    {
        "store_group_id": "ID0-y6z-85",
        "store_group_name": "Store Group A",
        "store_group_desc": "This is the desc of store group A",
        "AllstoreGroups": [
            {
                "store_id": "store 1",
                "store_name": "store A",
                "description": "This is the description of store 1",
                "org_id": "org id 1",
                "storeGroups": [
                    "ID0-y6z-85",
                    "ID4-y7z-27"
                ]
            },
            {
                "store_id": "store 2",
                "store_name": "store B",
                "description": "This is the description of store 2",
                "org_id": "org id 1",
                "storeGroups": [
                    "ID0-y6z-85",
                    "ID4-y7z-27"
                ]
            },
            {
                "store_id": "store 5",
                "store_name": "store E",
                "description": "This is the description of store 5",
                "org_id": "org id 1",
                "storeGroups": [
                    "ID0-y6z-85"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "store_group_id": "ID4-y7z-27",
        "store_group_name": "Store Group B",
        "store_group_desc": "This is the desc of store group B",
        "AllstoreGroups": [
   {
                "store_id": "store 1",
                "store_name": "store A",
                "description": "This is the description of store 1",
                "org_id": "org id 1",
                "storeGroups": [
                    "ID0-y6z-85",
                    "ID4-y7z-27"
                ]
            },
            {
                "store_id": "store 2",
                "store_name": "store B",
                "description": "This is the description of store 2",
                "org_id": "org id 1",
                "storeGroups": [
                    "ID0-y6z-85",
                    "ID4-y7z-27"
                ]
            }
         ]
    }
]
```

I tried for-loops and maps but didn't get the desired array object.
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you add what you tried so far? On first read, it should be pretty straightforward: loop over the array of stores and then over their store groups. Check if storegroup exists in  first array, and if so, add store to the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May may map the arrayA then filter arrayB in order to achieve you expected result, here is an example

```js
let arrayA = [
  {
    store_group_id: 'ID0-y6z-85',
    store_group_name: 'Store Group A',
    store_group_desc: 'This is the desc of store group A'
  },
  {
    store_group_id: 'ID4-y7z-27',
    store_group_name: 'Store Group B',
    store_group_desc: 'This is the desc of store group B'
  }
];

let arrayB = [
  {
    store_id: 'store 1',
    store_name: 'store A',
    description: 'This is the description of store 1',
    org_id: 'org id 1',
    storeGroups: [ 'ID0-y6z-85', 'ID4-y7z-27' ]
  },
  {
    store_id: 'store 2',
    store_name: 'store B',
    description: 'This is the description of store 2',
    org_id: 'org id 1',
    storeGroups: [ 'ID0-y6z-85', 'ID4-y7z-27' ]
  },
  {
    store_id: 'store 5',
    store_name: 'store E',
    description: 'This is the description of store 5',
    org_id: 'org id 1',
    storeGroups: [ 'ID0-y6z-85' ]
  }
];

let expectedArray = arrayA.map((item, index) => {
    let allStoreGroups = arrayB.filter((groupItem, groupIndex) => {
        return groupItem.storeGroups.includes(item.store_group_id);
    });
    
    item.AllStoreGroups = allStoreGroups;
    return item;
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(expectedArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over arrays A and B then check of their `store_group_id`, like so:

```
const arrayA = [
  {
    store_group_id: "ID0-y6z-85",
    store_group_name: "Store Group A",
    store_group_desc: "This is the desc of store group A",
  },
  {
    store_group_id: "ID4-y7z-27",
    store_group_name: "Store Group B",
    store_group_desc: "This is the desc of store group B",
  },
]

const arrayB = [
  {
    store_id: "store 1",
    store_name: "store A",
    description: "This is the description of store 1",
    org_id: "org id 1",
    storeGroups: ["ID0-y6z-85", "ID4-y7z-27"],
  },
  {
    store_id: "store 2",
    store_name: "store B",
    description: "This is the description of store 2",
    org_id: "org id 1",
    storeGroups: ["ID0-y6z-85", "ID4-y7z-27"],
  },
  {
    store_id: "store 5",
    store_name: "store E",
    description: "This is the description of store 5",
    org_id: "org id 1",
    storeGroups: ["ID0-y6z-85"],
  },
]

for (let i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
  const currA = arrayA[i]

  for (let j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
    const currB = arrayB[j]

    if (currB.storeGroups.includes(currA.store_group_id)) {
      if (currA.AllstoreGroups === undefined) {
        currA.AllstoreGroups = []
      }

      currA.AllstoreGroups.push(currB)
    }
  }
}

console.log(arrayA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let arrayA = [
  {
    store_group_id: "ID0-y6z-85",
    store_group_name: "Store Group A",
    store_group_desc: "This is the desc of store group A"
  },
  {
    store_group_id: "ID4-y7z-27",
    store_group_name: "Store Group B",
    store_group_desc: "This is the desc of store group B"
  }
];

let arrayB = [
  {
    store_id: "store 1",
    store_name: "store A",
    description: "This is the description of store 1",
    org_id: "org id 1",
    storeGroups: ["ID0-y6z-85", "ID4-y7z-27"]
  },
  {
    store_id: "store 2",
    store_name: "store B",
    description: "This is the description of store 2",
    org_id: "org id 1",
    storeGroups: ["ID0-y6z-85", "ID4-y7z-27"]
  },
  {
    store_id: "store 5",
    store_name: "store E",
    description: "This is the description of store 5",
    org_id: "org id 1",
    storeGroups: ["ID0-y6z-85"]
  }
];

const arrC = arrayA.map((item) => {
  return {
    ...item,
    AllstoreGroups: getStoreGroups(item)
  };
});

function getStoreGroups(item) {
  const itemInStore = [];

  arrayB.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.storeGroups.includes(item.store_group_id)) {
      itemInStore.push(element);
    }
  });

  return itemInStore;
}

console.log(arrC)
```

In this way you are simply mapping the arrayA to have a structure like the one you want, and then, with the `getStoreGroups`, you watch inside the arrayB to find the element that has the current arrayAItem `store_group_id` inside the `storeGroups` array.

If you want to clean the code you could also use a `filter` function instead of `forEach` in the `getStoreGroups` function:

```
function getStoreGroups(item) {
  const itemInStore = arrayB.filter((element) =>
    element.storeGroups.includes(item.store_group_id)
  );

  return itemInStore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes only two loops (and should not take more for this job).

1. Gather all stores by their group.
2. Map an array with the groups and their associated stores.

```js
const
    arrayA = [{ store_group_id: 'ID0-y6z-85', store_group_name: 'Store Group A', store_group_desc: 'This is the desc of store group A' }, { store_group_id: 'ID4-y7z-27', store_group_name: 'Store Group B', store_group_desc: 'This is the desc of store group B' }],
    arrayB = [{ store_id: 'store 1', store_name: 'store A', description: 'This is the description of store 1', org_id: 'org id 1', storeGroups: ['ID0-y6z-85', 'ID4-y7z-27']}, { store_id: 'store 2', store_name: 'store B', description: 'This is the description of store 2', org_id: 'org id 1', storeGroups: ['ID0-y6z-85', 'ID4-y7z-27'] }, { store_id: 'store 5', store_name: 'store E', description: 'This is the description of store 5', org_id: 'org id 1', storeGroups: ['ID0-y6z-85'] }] ,
    storeGroups = arrayB.reduce((r, o) => o.storeGroups.reduce((q, id) => ((q[id] ??= []).push(o), q), r), {}),
    result = arrayA.map(o => ({ ...o, stores: storeGroups[o.store_group_id] || [] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```